# Adding varchar parameter to MySQLCommand

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to execute a MySQLCommand like so:

```
Dim comCommand As MySqlCommand

comCommand = New MySqlCommand("MyStoredProc", conConnection)
comCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

myParam = New MySqlParameter("?myParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) 'Error occurs here!
comCommand.Parameters.Add(myParam )
myParam .Value = "test"

comCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But I keep getting the following error when creating the "varchar" parameter:

> "Invalid data type"

It seems to be something to do with the "size" parameter, but I don't see what is wrong with it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using MySqlDbType instead of SqlDbType?

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.

Comment: i added it as an answer for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using MySqlDbType instead of SqlDbType?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use without size

```
New MySqlParameter("?myParam", SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

Comment: This does seem to work. But I think Derek's solution is probably the right one.